# Corner brace with countersink on opposite sides?

Tags: screws, bolts, hardware

Is there a special name for a corner brace which has the countersink on opposite sides? That being that on one leg of the "L" the countersink is on the side pointing out of the angle, where on the other leg it's pointing in? While searching I've only been able to find corner braces with the countersink on the inside of the "L", and I have a feeling it may just not be called a corner brace in other situations (as you probably wouldn't place it in a corner with such a countersink).

Comment: A picture or two would go a long ways toward helping to illustrate what you are asking about. I pretty much got lost trying to navigate your paragraph.

Comment: Why not buy a metal bracket and use a countersink on the requisite hole?

Comment: what do you need it for? ... that may be the search term to use

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess, but it might be an 'outside corner bracket'? You could modify a standard corner brackets countersunk openings by using a countersunk bit on the reverse-side of the bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few you might find use for:

[ONE](http://www.vandykes.com/2-58-natural-black-iron-corner/p/204986/), [TWO](http://www.vandykes.com/product.aspx?p=206088&green=2CEAAD3F-386D-5D7A-0311-057B8A1461EB), [THREE](http://www.whitechapel-ltd.com/category/corner.html),

[FOUR](http://www.homedepot.com/s/mending%2520plate?NCNI-5) Mending Plate - you bend, cut or shape these to your design. They come in all lengths & are readily available at Home Improvement stores, Hardware stores & Variety store's hardware aisles.

[image: Corner Braces]

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon your question because I was looking for the exact same thing. I finally found something on Amazon, apparently "reverse hole" should do it for searching. This particular item was exactly what I was looking for as I wanted to secure these wooden "box" cabinets I have to each other (as they are currently only connected through a central screw in the middle of the two boxes stacked on top of one another and I wanted to reinforce them so they don't spin and can be moved as a more stable unit instead of "spinning" when they're picked up). Hope this helps you out! https://smile.amazon.com/NNNJunhua-Stainless-Connection-Accessories-41%C3%9741%C3%9739mm/dp/B09CYNWYKC/ref=sr_1_53?dchild=1&keywords=outside%2Bcorner%2Bbracket&qid=1631769611&sr=8-53&th=1